# Does Pandas have a way to do time-based aggregation only for particular dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series of measurements over a period of months. The measurement happens at most once per day, but not every day. I also have particular dates for which I want to compute some metrics over the past 30 days. The dates do not necessarily overlap. I am looking for a built-in way to do this in Pandas.

I know about using rolling aggregation with offsets, but that gives me windows anchored on the days of the measurements, not the days I actually want the mean for.

I'll construct an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

T = pd.Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [T(2019, 8, 10),
                            T(2019, 8, 15),
                            T(2019, 8, 18)],
                   'measurement': [5, 4, 7]})
```

So here is an example data frame:

```
        date  measurement
0 2019-08-10            5
1 2019-08-15            4
2 2019-08-18            7
```

Here's what I know how to do:

```py
df.rolling('30d', on='date', closed='left',
           min_periods=0).aggregate('mean')
```

Output:

```
        date  measurement
0 2019-08-10          NaN
1 2019-08-15          5.0
2 2019-08-18          4.5
```

But these are not the dates I am interested in. What I actually want is to provide the dates for which to compute the mean:

```py
dates = [T(2019, 8, 12), T(2019, 8, 20)]

df.rolling('30d', TARGETS=dates, on='date',
           closed='left',
           min_periods=0).aggregate('mean')
```

Output:

```
        date  measurement
0 2019-08-12          NaN
1 2019-08-20          5.333333
```

I know that `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` does not actually have this functionality built-in. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: not completely sure what is needed, will this work for you `df.query('date.between("2019-08-12", "2019-08-20")').mean()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no. For each day in the target dates, I want the mean over the previous 90 days. I can use a  solution like yours to make a 90 day window for each target date, so I could build up an iterative solution, but I am hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: Can you not just calculate the rolling mean and then select the dates your interested in?